# Как получить Bitmap из текущего видимого фрагмента? (FragmentActivity + PagerAdapter + Universal Image Loader)

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, universal-image-loader

Для просмотра галереи фотографий использую `FragmentActivity` в связке с адаптером `PagerAdapter`.

В его методе `public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position)` подгружаю картинки c помощью UIL.

Когда пытаюсь получить текущий видимый(!) `Bitmap` через:

```
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
    mCurrentView = (View)object;

    ImageView currentImageView = (ImageView) mCurrentView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) currentImageView.getDrawable();
    currentLoadedImage = bd.getBitmap(); // < ----- java.lang.NullPointerException
}
```

то ловлю Exception в последней строчке. Предполагаю что UIL не успевает к этому времени подгрузить картинку...

Когда пытаюсь получить доступ к `Bitmap` в:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(MyActivity.imagesArray[position], imageView, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {

...

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

    // тут

    }
});
```

то получаю не текущую `Bitmap`, а ту, которую адаптер подгрузил последней (при загрузке страницы грузятся две соседние).

Кто сталкивался и какое решение было найдено?
Спасибо!

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**

```
class GalleryPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    .....

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    final View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pb);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Zakazchik_full.imagesArray[position], imageView, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    });

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }
```

слушатель:

```
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int p1, float p2, int p3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int p1) {
            Log.e("onPageSelected: ", "" + p1);

            ImageLoader il = ImageLoader.getInstance();

            ImageSize targetSize = new ImageSize(200, 200);

            il.loadImage(Zakazchik_full.imagesArray[p1], targetSize, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    //super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);
                    Log.e("LOADING STARTED", "");
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    //super.onLoadingFailed(imageUri, view, failReason);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    //super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
                    currentLoadedImage = loadedImage;
                    Log.e("LOADING COMPLITE", "");
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int p1) {

        }
    };

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
    if (page == 0) {
        pageChangeListener.onPageSelected(0);
    } else {
        mViewPager.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
            }
        });
    }
```

А по поводу получить `getDrawable`, это значит в методе `onPageSelected` получить текущий `фрагмент` -> `imageview` -> `drawable`?

Comment: Не очень понял что именно вам надо, но у `ViewPager` есть слушатель листания страниц `OnPageChangeListener`. В нём в методе `onPageSelected` вы получаете текущую позицию в `ViewPager`

Comment: Сейчас как раз в нем определяю позицию но по каким-то непонятным мне причинам, именно в этом методе не хочет выполняться ImageLoader il = ImageLoader.getInstance();
                il.loadImage(Zakazchik_full.imagesArray[p1], new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {...};

Comment: `не хочет выполняться` значит падает или просто не вызываются методы окончания/начала загрузки?..

Comment: Второй вариант ответа. Log.e, записанные в обоих методах (начало/окончание) не вызываются.

Comment: Покажите в вопросе как вы повесили слушатель смены страниц и как в нём грузите картинку. И кстати, у `ImageView` ведь есть, вроде, метод типа `getDrawable()`... Может им воспользоваться вместо загрузки чрез UIL?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Непонятно зачем вы через раннабл устанавливаете страницу. А про дроабле все верно